# Database unit testing (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing, dbunit

I am trying to find a way to unit test my MySQL dependant code. I know how I would like it to work but cannot find the solution that would work for me. I have looked into DBUnit, but it would seem (if I am not mistaken) that this would require a running database and just aids with the unit testing side of things. I would like some way to avoid running a mysql database when testing. What would work great would be some sort of MySQL spoof driver that actually stored data in memory, rather than needing to access a real persistent database.

In my code it is hard coded to access a MySQL database so I can't just inject some mock object. The way I would like it to work is that when my code calls:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, username, password);
```

It actually gets some other local database that can either be configured via maven or in the setUp of the maven test. I have looked into memory based databases such as HSQLDB but can't find a way for it to spoof the MySQL driver.

Are there any tools that provide what I am looking for? Do you have any good methods for testing MySQL dependant code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692398/how-do-i-make-a-mysql-database-run-completely-in-memory
When unit testing remember to populate the database first before initiating the main program.

Comment: I am not sure how I would use this without having an actual mysql server running. However that thought did make me think about an embedded mysql server to run during my unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I have had several projects in which I had to do integrations test against a running MySql server. Instead of spending time setting it up every time, I developed a [library](https://github.com/stumpdk/MySql.Server) that sets up a local running instance of MySQL every time you run your tests.

With that you get a test database that acts like the real thing (because it is) without having to set it up.

DBUnit is also a good alternative if you want to mock the database integration (as far as I know, there is no need for a real MySql server when using DBUnit).

Comment: I think I ended up going with a similar approach using the MySQL embedded version as part of the test dependencies. I made a project called MyUnit which when extended would instantiate and destroy a MySQL database before and after tests. DBUnit looks of interest so will also take a look at that. The need for this has actually come up again on a project I am working on so I will take a look at the options again.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19279391/416300. This guy wrote a Maven plugin to start and stop a MySQL DB before and after his test.

Comment: That's right, and it can be used when developing Java applications.